# truffle test - does not Assert (Erc20, Solidity)

Tags: solidity, erc-20, truffle-test

I am probably doing something wrong but can't see what exactly.

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";

contract TestABC {
    function totalSupplyTest() public {
        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;
        Assert.equal(a, b, "message ABC");
    }
}
```

Command:

```
$ truffle test
```

Result:

```
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/TestABC.sol



  0 passing (3ms)
```

The expected output should say:

> 1 passing (... ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity#test-function-names):

> Like test contract names, all test functions must start with `test`,
>   lowercase.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";

contract TestABC {
    function testTotalSupplyTest() public {
        bool a = true;
        bool b = true;
        Assert.equal(a, b, "message ABC");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/TestABC.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test-119105-5627-di9xqz.t2n2p
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang

  TestABC
    ✓ testTotalSupplyTest (71ms)

  1 passing (9s)
```